# material ui (mui) button have incorrect styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

why do my MUI button components look like this instead of like the docs
no external .css file or theme changes besides the ones listed
I have the roboto font installed as well and working on the typography
I want whatever changes I make to be global

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import "@fontsource/roboto/300.css";
import "@fontsource/roboto/400.css";
import "@fontsource/roboto/500.css";
import "@fontsource/roboto/700.css";

import "./index.css";
import Home from "./views/Home";
import Login from "./views/Login";
import Register from "./views/Register";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    Button: {
      defaultProps: {
        fontSize: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
});
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

```
<Button variant="contained" style={{ width: 150, height: 50 }}>
          I'm a Doctor
</Button>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEdAT.png

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing an import inside the component where the button is?

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
```

And I think the syntax for themes is wrong, you should be using `MuiButton` instead of `Button` inside `components` entry.

Comment: this is App.js not where I'm calling the Button, and MuiButton doesn't work either

Comment: @KareemEtefy provide the component code where you're using the Button